# How to create a Drupal View of Open and Resolved Cases

Tags: civicase, drupal-views

Goal is to recreate the CiviCRM Summary of Involvement Dashlet in Views.

Problem arises when I try to count both open and resolved Cases in one View.

Table should look like:

**Columns:** Case Type/Open Cases/Resolved Cases

Row 1 (Case Type 1)

Row 2 (Case Type 2)

Row 3 (Case Type 3)

with the number of open cases and resolved cases for each case type in the corresponding row.

I can accomplish it with a view and an attachment view, but not a single view.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried Aggregation which is a feature under Advanced on the View.

Comment: I have and it's working tremendously with cases that are either open or resolved, which is an exposed filter on the form.  Ideally, I'd like it to show both without the filter.

Comment: other idea that i have no experience with but often wonder if it might help in such situations, is the ability to include a view in a view. sorry i don't have any pointers on how to do this

Comment: I appreciate the ideas.  I've already got the functionality, this is just me trying to clean house a bit.  I've been trying to stay away from Views Field View module due to overhead, but may give it  try just to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we decided against this approach and went with a simple view with a Case Status exposed filter.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to create a UNION in your view. [Here are instructions for doing so](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31786/how-to-create-a-union-of-two-views). The top answer says to use custom code, but farther down is a link to the [Extra Views Handlers](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_extra_handlers) module which may be able to do it.